# converting matlab inline command to different

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm working in Matlab and I have written the following script with the intent to import into Excel but when I run the Matlab C++ Coder, it tells me that my inline command isn't supported.

```
function f = moody(ed,Re)
if Re<0
 error(fprintf('Reynolds number = %f cannot be negative',Re));
elseif Re<2000
 f = 64/Re;  return      %  laminar flow
end
if ed>0.05
 error(fprintf('epsilon/diameter ratio = %f is not on Moody chart',ed));
end
findf =  inline('1.0/sqrt(f)+2.0*log10(ed/3.7+2.51/(Re*sqrt(f)))','f','ed','Re');
fi = 1/(1.8*log10(6.9/Re+(ed/3.7)^1.11))^2;   %  initial guess at f
dfTol = 5e-6;
f = fzero(findf,fi,optimset('TolX',dfTol,'Display','off'),ed,Re);`
```

How can I rewrite the `findf = inline` command using anonymous functions or arrayfun commands so that the compiler will work?

Answer (score 0):

findf = @(f,ed,Re) 1.0/sqrt(f)+2.0*log10(ed/3.7+2.51/(Re*sqrt(f)))